# Pathauto changing drupal_get_path file path

Tags: 7, files, path-aliases

Pathauto changed where `drupal_get_path` looks for an image path I'm calling.

```
<img src="<?php print drupal_get_path('theme', 'maafs_subpage'); ?>/images/iafe.jpg" alt="Iafe the Network">
```

This was accessing `http://localhost/maafs/sites/all/themes/maafs_subpage/images/iafe.jpg`

Now it's trying to access `http://localhost/maafs/news/sites/all/themes/maafs_subpage/images/iafe.jpg`

Is there a work around for this or is there a better way of getting the path for the image?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you accessing this link from a subpage? It would seem that it is not appropriately pulling from the Drupal root when you are making the call (from a page other than the homepage).

You can use the global variable `$base_path` to get the Drupal root. More information on this global variable: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/base_path/7

Comment: Glad you got it working!